# Slow app changing page in WP8

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have an app with a ListBox; when the user taps an item i launch a new page that invoke a MVVM method and the fills its ListBox. When the user taps the first ListBox it does not change page immediately, waits 2-3 seconds and then shows the new page and it is not responsive. How can i activate the new page, showing the ProgressIndicator and fill the new list?
Here is the code for the second list:

```
        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            int id;
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("id"))
            {
                id = Convert.ToInt16(NavigationContext.QueryString["id"]);
                SystemTray.SetIsVisible(this, true);
                SystemTray.SetOpacity(this, 0.5);

                progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
                progressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
                progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
                SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, progressIndicator);

                var x=await App.viewModel.MyDBMethod(id);
                this.DataContext = App.viewModel;

                this.mPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
                progressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
                progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = false;

            }
        }
      }
```

Comment: how long does var x=await App.viewModel.MyDBMethod(id); take?

Comment: How about moving some of this logic in the Loaded event of the page? I don't know exactly your case, but perhaps showing the page and afterwards waiting for the data to come might be a better experience... (?)